# How do I write a function that can take in an array of two possible sizes?

Tags: arrays, rust

I have two functions that do the same thing; the only difference is that they take in an array of different sizes. How can I refactor this code such that I don't get duplicate code?

```
fn foo(arr: &[[u8; 21]; 21]) -> [[u8; 21]; 21] {
    // some operations that need to iterate through arr
}

fn bar(arr: &[[u8; 25]; 25]) -> [[u8; 25]; 25] {
    // identical operations as foo
}
```

I tried using generics:

```
fn foo<T>(arr: &T) -> T {
  // some operations
}
```

This doesn't work because Rust has no idea that `arr` is an array, and I'm not able to call things like `arr.len()`.

Another idea is to use a `Vec` instead, but I worry it comes at a cost of performance and memory.

Comment: This sounds like a good case for the upcoming [const generics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html) feature.

Comment: Have a look at [generic-array](https://crates.io/crates/generic-array).

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9ddab63118237c02cae1226ea8f2afc2)

Comment: Thanks everyone, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already mentioned, consider using *const generics* (the `const N: usize`), which are stable since rustc version 1.50.0.

```
fn foo<const N: usize>(arr: [u8; N]) -> [u8; N] {
    // some operations
    arr
}
```